AccountDoesNotExists, how to create to create ATA using createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction
If AccountDoesNotExists how can I create ATA's for many users using createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction on the frontend side

You can use the getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount method from the @solana/spl-token library
import { getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount } from "@solana/spl-token";

let mint = new PublicKey("Ao7ucCrBERm5tgQwM6tfXLbDA1Fg9DTznVu3SMYrpFot"); // spl token program
let toPubKey = new PublicKey("devu5C7Jg52KXd2Uyo5okGESYyKtQPMx8sme6vM11xK");

let toTokenAccount = await (
    await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
        conn,
        signer,
        mint,
        signer.publicKey
    )
).address;

ref: https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/functions/getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount.html

What I want to do is this thing, how could I simulate the Transaction?
`code``
const transaction = new web3.Transaction().add(
spl.createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
// spl.ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
// spl.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
mintPubkey,
associatedTokenPubkey,
ownerPubkey,
payer.publicKey
)
);
''code'

call simiulate tx rpc method, by default sendTransaction simulates transactions unless you set it to false in the pre-flight options. Jon's answer here might help const response = await connection.simulateTransaction(iTx, config, true)
